# Append data to a file in C++ but overwrite if the program is re-executed

Tags: c++, append, ofstream

I want to append data to a file in a function like so:

```
void Fill( string fileName ){
  ofstream outputFile(fileName, ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
  outputFile << data1 << " " << data2 << endl;
  outputFile.close();
}
```

This function is then used in a loop to write to different files if certain conditions are met. But I want to begin with empty files when the program is run, i.e. not to append to old data. How can I do this? 
Hope I made this clear.
Thanks!

Comment: Open the file without `app` the first time. After that open with `app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to open all of the files your program uses without std::ofstream::app in some a function that you call once at the beginning in order to truncate them.

```
void resetFiles()
{
    static char * fileNames[] = {
        // Fill this with filenames of the files you want to truncate
    };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( fileNames ) / sizeof( fileNames[ 0 ] ); ++i )
        std::ofstream( fileNames[ i ] );
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    resetFiles();

    ...
}
```

EDIT: Since you did specify you're looking for more elegant solution, here's what I've come up with. Basically you declare a new class that inherits from std::ofstream with static std::map< std::string, bool > member called record. You add a constructor that lets you specify the filename. It then looks up if the file has been already opened once by checking if key fileName exists in record. If not, it opens it with std::ofstream::trunc and sets record[ fileName ] to true. This way, when the file is opened for the second time, it knows that it has to open it with std::ofstream::app.

```
class OutFile : public std::ofstream
{
    static std::map< std::string, bool > record;

    // Helper function
    static std::ios_base::openmode hasBeenOpened( std::string fileName )
    {
        // Test if the key is present
        if( record.find( fileName ) == record.end() )
        {
            record[ fileName ] = true;
            return std::ofstream::trunc;
        }
        else
        {
            return std::ofstream::app;
        }
    }

public:
    OutFile( const char * filename )
    : std::ofstream( filename, hasBeenOpened( std::string( filename ) ) ) {}
};

// Don't forget to initialize record
map< std::string, bool > OutFile::record;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do at the moment, just wanted to know if there was a more elegant solution to this, not having to have the extra function : )
I'll wait a day more and will accept this answer if nothing other comes up.
Thanks!

Comment: Ooft, that is hefty! I like the idea you came up with, but by more elegant I guess I meant _less code to write_ haha, thanks anyways! I ended up using the extra function to clear the files and then simply use append. Marking as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ofstream::app` parameter you are passing into the function indicates that you want to append to a file if it already exists.  The default behavior is what you are looking for.  Remove that part,

So:

```
ofstream outputFile(fileName, ofstream::out);
```

Comment: This will overwrite the output file everytime I call my function `Fill`. But I want to append while in a loop, but work with empty files from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with `ofstream::trunc`, then pass that filestream to your `Fill` function (instead of a filename string) later to append the new data.

This is an incomplete example:

```
void Fill(ofstream& outputFile) {
  outputFile << data1 << " " << data2 << endl;
}

int main() {
  ofstream outputFile(fileName, ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);
  Fill(outputFile);
  outputFile.close();
}
```

(This assumes you're writing other data to the file elsewhere. If you're only touching this file from the `Fill` function, then David's answer to just remove the `ofstream::app` from `Fill` is much better.

Comment: Sorry if I made this unclear. I **want** to append data to the file inside my loop so the output in the end would look like
    _data1_ _data2_
    _data1_ _data2_
    etc....
If I omit `app`, I end up with a single line in the file, which is not the desired result.
My intention was simply to start with empty files rather than to append to data from last run.

Comment: That's exactly what this code does. It clears the output file when the program starts, and appends data each time it runs through the loop. Here's a working example: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0SMSPE5LwXAHTvCV